# Visual Studio 2017 add existing item as a copy

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have just installed VS2017 Version 15.6.6 so that I could follow an online course to learn C++.
I created a blank solution and added a project to it.
When I clicked "Add->Existing item..." and browsed to the cpp file, I was expecting the file to be copied from the original location into the new location and added to the project but it seems to be a link back to the original, so if the original file is moved or deleted it cannot then be found in the project. There is no little drop down arrow on the Add button that I have seen mentioned elsewhere which allows to select copy or link.
Has this functionality been removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's seem to be removed. You need to copy the files manual in the Windows Explorer and then add "existing" item.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that, it seems like a backwards step though!